# Como usar "include/require" no CodeIgniter da forma certa?

Tags: php, codeigniter, aplicação-web, mvc

Estou migrando do `PHP` para o `CodeIgniter`, e gostaria de saber, como usar os `include` ou `require` de forma certa no meu código?

Comment: Da mesma forma que usaria no _PHP_ puro. Não há qualquer modo diferente de fazer isso no _CodeIgniter_. Mas se sua pergunta se aplica a um contexto, mostre o contexto. Dependendo do que for, vc pode nem precisar de um _include_, e sim de uma biblioteca, ou um _helper_.

Comment: Depende do que você pretende fazer, mas, CodeIgniter é um framework escrito em PHP, a diferença é nenhuma, mas, a forma de fazer isso é diferente com certeza, mostre exemplos !!!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maioria das coisas você vai usar a classe load do CodeIgniter. Por exemplo:

```
$this->load->library('usuarios_class');
$this->load->view('usuarios/index-view');
$this->load->model('usuarios_model');
```

Você pode dar uma olhada na classe loader aqui: [Loader Class - CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html).

É importante visar que você entenda mais ou menos como funciona a estrutura MVC (Model, View, Controller). Entendendo isso, você consegue separar as funções de cada um e, usando a classe loader, chamar tudo o que você precisa.

Comment: Obrigado, ótima Resposta. Eu vi que também da para fazer o famoso "Include" dessa forma aqui   $this->load->view('header');  $this->load->view('corpo');  $this->load->view('footer');

Answer (score 3):

Olá.
A resposta marcada como correta não responde para quando a pessoa realmente precisar fazer um include ou require.

Para quem busca uma forma de incluir um PHP (neste caso uma library), mesmo conhecendo a estrutura MVC, segue:

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/minhaLibraryAqui.php');
```